# Artikel in »Die Augustiner-Bräu«

Tags: gender, article, proper-noun

Die Wandinschrift in der Gaststätte Türkenhof in der Türkenstraße 78 in München lautet:

> Die Augustiner-Bräu ist die älteste Brauerei Münchens.

Ist der Artikel *die* hier korrekt?

Eventuelle Erklärung:
Wenn man bei Wikipedia nachschaut, steht dort:

> Die Augustiner-Bräu **KG**  ist die älteste Brauerei Münchens.

Nachtrag:
Wie ist es denn mit:

> Die Max-Emmanuel ist die Gaststätte mit dem schlechtesten Biergarten in der Maxvorstadt?

Comment: Um mal wieder etwas Inhaltliches beizutragen: Bei Versicherungsgesellschaften ist es in der Branche und der Wirtschaftspresse sehr verbreitet, _Versicherung_ bzw. _Versicherungsgesellschaft_ in Firmennamen wegzulassen: _die Allianz Leben_, _die Münchener Rück_, _die Continentale Kranken_ usw.

Comment: @chirlu Ebenso zumindest umgangssprachlich *das Katharinen* und *das Olgäle* (Hospital) in Stuttgart oder die meisten Schulen in meiner Umgebung die als *das [Name]* (Gymnasien) oder *die [Name]* (Realschulen) bezeichnet werden.

Comment: Die Universität für angewandte Kunst ist in Wien jdf. ugs. nur als "die Angewandte" bekannt (siehe auch www.dieangewandte.at).

Comment: Zum Edit: Ja, wenn die Max-Emanuel-Gaststätte allen Gesprächspartnern so bekannt ist, dass den Zuhörern schon bei der Nennung des Namens sofort klar ist, wovon Du sprichst. Und wenn "Gaststätte" der übliche Terminus ist.

Comment: Der Artikel ist meiner Meinung nach hier überflüssig und dient nur dazu, bereits mit dem Satzanfang klarzumachen, dass es hier nicht um das Bier selbst, sondern um die Firma geht, die es herstellt.

Comment: **Diskussion entfernt** – Bitte nutzt Antworten (nicht Kommentare), um zu antworten, und diskutiert deren Korrektheit dort, falls nötig. Für die Schließung einer Frage ist ausschließlich die Frage selbst ausschlaggebend, nicht das Verhalten des Fragestellers. Falls irgendwer weiteren Diskussionsbedarf über die Schließung, Moderation oder über die oben genannten Punkte hat, möge er bitte eine Frage auf Meta stellen.

Answer (score 7):

Ja, der Artikel ist korrekt.

Der Satz ist eine Verkürzung von

> Die Augustiner-Bräu Brauerei ist die älteste Brauerei Deutschlands

Um das Wort *Brauerei*  nicht sinnlos zu doppeln, wird es in solchen Fällen gerne mal weggelassen.

Das Beispiel ist analog zu

> Der Travemündener ist der älteste Leuchtturm Deutschlands

oder

> Das in Lübeck ist das bekannteste Tor in Norddeutschland.

Answer (score 4):

Hier geht es ja darum, dass "Augustiner-Bräu" ein eigenständiger Name ist, und dass die Augustiner-Bräu ja eine Brauerei ist und somit "die" richtig ist.

Comment: Tja, es gibt aber Gaststätten "Zum Augustiner-Bräu". Die sind dann alle grammatikalisch falsch?

Comment: Nein. Denn es heißt umgangssprachlich "Der Augustiner-Bräu", wenn man in München wohnt (siehe auch mein "sinnbefreiter Kommentar"), weil es sich als Eigenname eingebürgert hat. Der Artikel "die" ergibt sich durch das Wort "Brauerei", das in dem Satz "... ist die älteste Brauerei ..." vorkommt. Ich weiß halt nicht genau, was Du daran nicht begreifen kannst.

Comment: Außerdem heißt es im Bayrischen "Der Bräu" für etwas, was gebraut wurde.

Comment: Ich hätte _das_ Bräu gesagt, aber auch dann stimmt "zum Augustiner Bräu".

Comment: Warum zwei Downvotes??

Comment: @Ingmar... ja, es gibt das Bräu, aber wenn ich meine Firma "Die Flusspferd (GmbH) nennen will, dann ist es "die Flusspferd". Beispiel gefällt nicht? Dann nimm einfach "die Bild"

Answer (score 3):

Ja, denn sowohl *KG* als auch *Brauerei* sind weiblich. 
EDIT:
Die Tatsache, dass es oft "das ____bräu" heißt, spielt hier keine Rolle, denn es geht um einen Eigennamen einer Firma.
Vgl.: "die Bild"

Comment: Das ist keine Antwort, sondern ein Kommentar, da im tatsächlichen Text steht "Augustiner-Bräu" ohne " KG" oder "Brauerei".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Karl ... ich sehe das Problem nicht. Es ist eine Brauerei. Sie heißt "Augustiner Bräu". Und sie ist eine KG, wie du selbst in deiner Frage feststellst. Was soll also die Frage? Was soll man denn antworten, was du nicht selbst weißt. Warum hat Carsten keine Downvotes? Oder Sunlog? Meine Antwort ist inhaltlich nicht anders.

Comment: @Jan... I am missing your downvotes on Carstens answer. Why? It's the exact same content.

Comment: @Emanuel because I was taken there via Low-Quality posts review queue ;) (and I didn't downvote iirc).

Comment: @jan... made an edit

Comment: Much better. Now how do I unvote to delete … Damn .__.

Comment: @Jan: don't vote on "delete" in the first place? Deleting an otherwise harmless answer generally is not a good idea as this makes all efforts to improve it impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Gesellschaften werden oft als weiblich behandelt, unabhängig davon, ob ein Zusatz wie „KG“ angibt, dass sie welche sind.

Comment: Auch die anderen Zusätze – OHG, GbR, GmbH, AG – verwenden ja alle irgendwo das Wort *Gesellschaft* … aber ansonsten nicht falsch. ;)

Comment: @Jan daher "wie" ;)